# How do I make a loop in jQuery so that theres a number added to the end of my divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops

I want the numbers in the div id's and div classes to loop and be from 0 to however many divs I have.. How can I accomplish this? I've tried to put it in a for loop but it doesn't work for some reason..

```
$("#bokautbildning0").hide();
$(".boka_btn0").click(function(){
        $("#bokautbildning0").slideToggle();
        var scrollToId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollToId).offset().top - 270
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });


$("#bokautbildning1").hide();
$(".boka_btn1").click(function(){
        $("#bokautbildning1").slideToggle();
        var scrollToId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollToId).offset().top - 270
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });


$("#bokautbildning2").hide();
$(".boka_btn2").click(function(){
        $("#bokautbildning2").slideToggle();
        var scrollToId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollToId).offset().top - 270
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

Here's the code with the loop I tried:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    $("#bokautbildning" + i).hide();
    $(".boka_btn" + i).click(function(){
        $("#bokautbildning" + i).slideToggle();
        var scrollToId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollToId).offset().top - 270
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You question isn't very clear. What are you trying to accomplish and where is the loop?

Comment: Why don't you give them all the same class, instead of numbering the classes? Classes aren't very useful if they're unique for each DIV.

Comment: Which number 1 are you talking about? The one after `.boka_btn` or the one after `#bokautbildning1`?

Comment: Downvoted because of changing the essence of the question after receiving the first answers.

Comment: The OP realized as the first answers came in that he didn't accurately state his use case. That isn't a good reason to downvote him.

Comment: @CBauer the first version of the question was a valid question with a valid answer. That answer should've been accepted, and OP should've opened a new question (and possibly referenced to here). Fundamentally changing a question is a no-no, especially after receiving answers.

Comment: Honestly, as a user with 1k reputation you should be well above tantrums and petty activities like downvoting someone because your answer didn't get accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery for this would be pretty straightforward if you made use of data attributes. To wit:

Html example:

```
<div data-number="1"></div>
<div data-number="2"></div>
<div data-number="3"></div>
<div data-number="4"></div>
<div data-number="5"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$("div[data-number]").each(function() {
    var number = $(this).data("number");
    $(this).html(number);
    alert(number);
})
```

To see it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/uubxj55r/

Comment: It's a very long winded way of doing it. You can just use the index from the each loop. No need for data attributes.

Comment: So doing the anti-pattern of creating 1 class for every div on your page is more long winded then using a data-attribute to store the number and querying the divs on whether or not they have the data-number attribute...?

Comment: Thank you!! The data attributes and the each function was a much better solution!

Comment: @CBauer Not at all. This method is better than the OP's original. I think seeing [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xgk2jmmg/) using your test data is a better explanation of what I mean.

Comment: @JamieBarker I see what you mean. I'm not sure if OP is going to need to maintain the reference to the specific div# instance. If he does not, than I would suggest using your example code.

Comment: @CBauer Well according to the comment on my answer, they do (Might need to have been pointed out in the question, but hey ho!). Could you edit your answer slightly so I can revoke my negative vote?

Comment: If I add in the index to the function call, it won't work the way I intended. For example, if the order of div#s is div2 div5 div1 div4 div3 then it would no longer capture the right div during iteration (still not 100% sure of OP's code).

Answer (score 1):

**This answer was written for an older version of the question and is no longer correct.**

The best solution would be to add a class to all those elements and use that instead of ids to  run jQuery on. Let jQuery do the work to iterate over all those elements.

For example, give all elements `#bokautbildning`*`n`* the class `.bokautbildning` and change your javascript code to this:

```
$('.bokautbildning').hide();

$('.boka_btn1').click(function(){
    $('.bokautbildning').slideToggle();

    var scrollToId = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(scrollToId).offset().top - 270
    }, 500);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Updated my question, any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[Each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** and just make sure all items have the same class within each section. There is no need to use the numbering system that you are currently using.

```
$('.MyDivs').each(function(index){ //Loop through all the elements with class of 'MyDivs'
   var thisElement = $(this); //get the current element we're on in the loop
   thisElement.find('.bokautbildning').slideToggle(); //Find the element with class 'bokautbildning' within the current element in the loop and slideToggle it
   thisElement.find('.boka_btn').click(function() { //Find the element with classs 'boka_btn' within the current element in the loop and add a click listener
      //Code for click event happens here
   });
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/o85tk0s3/

Comment: I need the number system for another reason in the PHP code.. But thanks for the tip! :)